# How to verify if first line of CSV file matches the header names?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I would like to process CSV file of such structure:

```
header1,header2
val1.1, val1.2
val2.1, val2.2
```

But only if the first line contains both header names - otherwise throw an exception.

My current implementations using [Apache Common CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getContent()));

CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
            .withHeader("header1", "header2")
            .withSkipHeaderRecord());

for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) { /* records processing */ }
```

The problem is that the first line might have values different than header names and the file is still processed.

Comment: Refer: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withSkipHeaderRecord-- , you are skipping the header records anyway.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to process the headers as record, but I want to make sure they have the values I want.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [Java Doc of CSVFormat](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html):

### Referencing columns safely

If your source contains a header record, you can simplify your code and safely reference columns, by using withHeader(String...) with no arguments:

```java
 CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader();
```

This causes the parser to read the first record and use its values as column names. Then, call one of the CSVRecord get method that takes a String column name argument:

```java
 String value = record.get("Col1");
```

This makes your code impervious to changes in column order in the CSV file.

---

So you can just follow this and use first line as header, then validate headers [CSVParser#getHeaderNames](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getHeaderNames--).

Following is a simple demonstration:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

public class UseFirstRowAsHeader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String validHeaderCsv = "header1,header2\r\n"
                + "val1.1,val1.2\r\n"
                + "val2.1,val2.2";
        parseWithHeaderValidation(validHeaderCsv);
        String invalidHeaderCsv = "header1,header2,header3\r\n"
                + "val1.1,val1.2\r\n"
                + "val2.1,val2.2";
        parseWithHeaderValidation(invalidHeaderCsv);
    }

    private static void parseWithHeaderValidation(String validHeaderCsv) throws IOException {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(validHeaderCsv);
        List<String> expectedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
        expectedHeaders.add("header1");
        expectedHeaders.add("header2");
        try (CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withHeader().withAllowMissingColumnNames(false)
                .withSkipHeaderRecord())) {
            if (!csvParser.getHeaderNames().equals(expectedHeaders)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Not expected headers" + csvParser.getHeaderNames());
            }

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                System.out.println(csvRecord.get("header1") + "," + csvRecord.get("header2"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```